# How to run list of commands in centos server?

Tags: linux, scripting, command

I have few dedicated servers and couple VPS'es. I have to perform a list of copy paste commands (mostly) on all of them.

Total commands are around 18, a few of them require manual entry my me though.

So how to create or achieve such thing? I believe I'll have to create a .sh script? But how?

Most of the commads are like "wget install -zip"

```
Install unzip
Install etc

Wget abc.com/file.zip
Unzip file.zip
Cd file
Sh run.sh
```

Etc

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

Comment: Hi, can you pinpoint to the topic? I read them but it doesnt seem thats what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is several options
`<command1>; <command2>; <command3>` so split commands with semicolon, then next command will be executed when previous finish.

Second option is to split with `&&` `<command1>&& <command2>&& <command3>`, then next command will be executed when previous finish with success.

And next option is to write bash script, but in your case you should write script, starting from:

`#!/bin/bash
<execute first command>
<execute second command>
<execute third command>`